# Charting Library for Windows Phone 7 with Zooming & Panning?

Tags: windows-phone-7, charts, zooming, panning

I'm looking for a Silverlight charting library to use in my Windows Phone 7 project to visualize 50-100 data points. I'd like the series to be zoomable and pannable and be able to attach to these events.

I've so far looked at the [Silverlight Toolkit for WP7](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/), however it seems it does not support zooming or panning at all.

Is there any component out there I could use for this? Seems like a pretty basic requirement for a charting library on the phone, yet I've failed to find any.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The charting controls from [VisiBlox](http://www.visiblox.com/) support WP7 are free and come highly recommended.

Update:
With surprising coincidence, this [video demonstrating functionality](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FHsulCfx4Uc) has just been posted.

Comment: Thanks Matt, from the video it seems this is pretty much what I'm looking for.

Comment: Matt lacey: I think the library is free to use. But I guess we can not use the free version in an application which will be distributed for end users. Please clarify.

Comment: @Krishnan I am not a lawyer. If you have a query about the licensing of the controls you should raise it with them.