# how would I implement realtime graphing in Silverlight/WP7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, graphing

I'm trying to implement realtime graphing of data in my WP7 app. Can someone point me in the right direction on how to go about doing this?  To clarify, by real-time I mean a graph that updates every second.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The charting controls from [VisiBlox](http://www.visiblox.com/) support WP7, are free and come highly recommended.

There's also a [video demonstrating functionality on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FHsulCfx4Uc).

X-Ref: [Charting Library for Windows Phone 7 with Zooming & Panning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069617/charting-library-for-windows-phone-7-with-zooming-panning/5069721#5069721)

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on what you mean by realtime but I am using amCharts in my WP7 app to graph river flow data and it was easy to setup and use. http://blog.amcharts.com/2010/08/introducing-quick-charts-for-windows.html